# System.Diagnostics.Trace class in notepad++

Tags: c#, .net

I tried doing this

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

public class Sample
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Stream traceText = File.Create("trace.txt");
        TextWriterTraceListener textListener = new TextWriterTraceListener(traceText);
        Trace.Listeners.Add(textListener);

        Trace.Write("wth is goin on? I should be appearin in a txt file :(");

        Trace.Flush(); 
    }
}
```

and compiled with cmd,
but the program just creates an empty trace.txt file.. why?

btw I'm using the latest .NET Framework version and I'm using notepad++ not VS

Comment: You should also be closing the stream (`traceText.Close()`), but I'm not sure that this is your issue. I can't reproduce, are you sure that you closed the file in Notepad++ and reopened it? Works fine for me as-is.

Comment: yesss.. i'm reopening it...

Comment: let me try reopening my whole notepad++ application

Comment: still not working :/

Comment: What is the file size? Try opening it in another program (like notepad or VS), Notepad++ has some strange caching issues I've run into. Also try writing to the temp directory instead (c:\temp\trace.txt).

Comment: yes it is the right folder.. i even saw it popping up...

Comment: the filesize i 0 bytes

Comment: Right click your project in Visual studio, select properties, build tab, and ensure that "Define TRACE constant" checkbox is checked.

Comment: i tried  opening c:\temp\trace.txt but it doesnt exist

Comment: i'm not using visual studio.. i'm using notepad++... maybe that's the problem??

Comment: and i compile through cmd...

Comment: Ah, then put "#define TRACE" as the very first line in your file, then recompile

Comment: OHHH YEAH!!! IT FINALLY WORKS!! THANKS BRO!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most `Trace` class methods (such as `Write`) are marked with `[Conditional("TRACE")]` attribute, which means calls to them are stripped off by compiler unless corresponding constant is defined.

This constant is usually set by default when you create project in visual studio, but since you compile yourself from command line - you need to define it yourself.

For that, either put

```
#define TRACE
```

as the very first line in your code file, or pass `/d:TRACE` option to compiler when you compile from command line.